# Priority of my.ini location

Tags: mysql

I need the config file that mysqld.exe is using. Is this the right order?

```
a) --defaults-file="c:\path\to\my.ini"
b) <programdir>\..\my.ini
c) %systemroot%\my.ini
```

And are there any more?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the [MySQL documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/option-files.html), the order of precedence for configuration files is

> ```
> WINDIR\my.ini, WINDIR\my.cnf
> C:\my.ini, C:\my.cnf
> INSTALLDIR\my.ini, INSTALLDIR\my.cnf
> --defaults-extra-file=path
> ```

Loaded in order from top to bottom, if present.

Comment: Yep.  The cnf gets loaded after the ini, overwriting any common variables.